# How to structure properly MUI Card in React + TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a card component in React using Material-UI (MUI) with TypeScript, but I'm having trouble structuring it as needed. The card is supposed to represent a car and includes various components such as text, an image, checkboxes, a rating, and a button.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Rating from '@mui/material/Rating';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

type MyCardProps = {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  imageSrc: string;
  characteristic1: string;
  characteristic2: string;
  characteristic3: string;
  characteristic4: string;
};

export const MyCard: React.FC<MyCardProps> = ({
  title,
  content,
  imageSrc,
  characteristic1,
  characteristic2,
  characteristic3,
  characteristic4,
}) => {
  return (
    <Card style={{
      display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '312px', height: '265px',
    }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="div" textAlign="center">
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          {content}
        </Typography>
        <ul>
          <li>{characteristic1}</li>
          <li>{characteristic2}</li>
          <li>{characteristic3}</li>
          <li>{characteristic4}</li>
        </ul>
      </CardContent>
      <img src={imageSrc} alt="Car" style={{ width: '150px', height: '84.28px', marginLeft: '16px' }} />
      <div style={{ marginLeft: '16px' }}>
        <Checkbox /> Checkbox 1
        <Checkbox /> Checkbox 2
        <Rating name="rating" defaultValue={0} precision={0.5} />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          See more
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MyCard;
```

I want the card to have a specific layout with elements arranged in a row. However, I'm facing issues with the alignment and overall structure.

Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on how to structure this MUI card properly to achieve the desired layout? Any suggestions or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is how it looks now]

[image: This is how I need to make it to look like]

Answer (score 2):

For start, I suggests to use the `<CardHeader />` and `<CardActions/>` components along the `<CardContent />`, therefore it would be easier to center the title, and for the rating component and See more button to be positioned correctly. You can find an example on the material ui docs page : https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#system-RecipeReviewCard.tsx